# How do i make a word (in column A1) automatically show a value (in column B1)

Tags: formatting, conditional-formatting

Can someone please explain how to do the following:

I have two columns (A&B) in excel. If i type a word in column A1 - say Paper, i want to have a value show automatically in column B1 - say 25. Can you kindly explain how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: How would Excel know how to match "Paper" with "25". Do you have a lookup table somewhere (maybe on another sheet?) that matches "Paper" with "25"?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IF` function. In B1, enter the formula:

```
=IF(A1="Paper",25,"")
```

B1 shows 25 when the value of A1 is paper. Otherwise, B1 is empty.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please, can you then explain how to do this with different words, like the following example:

I have two columns (A&B) and about 30 rows in excel.  I want to put in different words - Paper in A1, Chair in A2, Glass in A3,and have values (say 25, 33, 47) show automatically in B1, B2, B3. How do i pre-set the excel doc such that when someone types - PAPER - in line A22, it automatically shows the value (25) in B22, or Glass in A29 with value (47) showing automatically in B29 . Can you kindly explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can someone please explain how to do this with different words:

I have two columns (A&B) and about 40 rows in excel. I want to put in different words, say - Paper in A1, Chair in A2, Glass in A3,and have values (say 25, 33, 47) show automatically in B1, B2, B3. [I know IF(A1="Paper",25,"") helps address this for row A1].

But, how can i pre-set the excel doc, for multiple words, such that when someone types - PAPER - in line A22, it automatically shows the value (25) in B22, or Glass in A29 with value (47) showing automatically in B29 . Can you kindly explain how to do that?

Comment: This is not an Answer, but a question. You should delete the answer and post as a question, perhaps with a reference back here.